# Can't create multiple tables in ionic1 using SQLite

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm building a mobile app using Ionic & Cordova and I need to store data in a couple of table in a local db, so I'm using SQLite.

In my app.js I have this:

```js
var db = null;

var weatherApp = angular.module('weather', ['ionic', 'ngCordova']);

weatherApp.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite, Cities) {

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova) {
      db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: 'weather.db', location: 'default'});

      create table for storing favourites
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS favourites (id integer primary key, name text, openWeatherId integer)');
      create table for storing the current location of the device
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS location (id integer primary key, openWeatherId integer');

    //also tried
      // db.transaction(function (tx) {
      //   //create table for storing favourites
      //   tx.executeSql(db, 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS favourites (id integer primary key, name text, openWeatherId integer)');
      // });

      // db.transaction(function (tx) {
      //   //create table for storing the current location of the device
      //   tx.executeSql(db, 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS location (id integer primary key, openWeatherId integer');
      // });

      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'SELECT tbl_name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = "table"').then(function (res) {
        var tables = [];
        if (res.rows.length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
            if (res.rows.item(i).tbl_name !== "android_metadata"){
              tables.push(res.rows.item(i).tbl_name);
            }
          }
          console.log(tables); 
          // gives:
          //   Array(1)
          //     0 : "favourites"
        } else {
          console.log('no tables in db!');
        }
      }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

When I run this (cordova run android) on a physical android device, only 1 table is created, favourites, the other location is not.

Any ideas why?  Thanks!

Comment: Just tried switching the order of the 2 create statements and weirdly, still only favourites is created. WAT!?

Comment: Did you notice the error at the end of the 2nd sql query? You need to close the parenthesis: openWeatherId integer'); -> openWeatherId integer)');

Comment: Thank you  Gustavo - now THAT was a dumb error!  Please submit as an answer and I'll mark it correct :)

Comment: done. 4 eyes see more than 2 :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a typo in the second SQL query:

```
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS location (id integer primary key, openWeatherId integer');
```

Closing the parenthesis fixed the problem:

```
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS location (id integer primary key, openWeatherId integer)');
```